# Schema can't be modified since the application is paused

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, error, managed-property, search-schema

I am working on a site provisioning project in SharePoint online. I am heavily using custom display templates and content by search web parts for the site . I have managed properties that I need to use to filter the search results. 
But when I am trying to modify any managed property, I get this weird error message

> ```
> Schema can't be modified since the application is paused
> ```

and I can't proceed further. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I saw many forums discussing this and concluding it saying, wait for the system to come out of the paused state, but would like to know what is the `wait period` approximately and what is the cause for this behavior.

Comment: wait for sometime for  application to come out of the paused state.

Comment: Is the Search Service Application paused? If so, why?

Comment: Hey guys, the issue goes away after sometime, for me I tried after a day and it was working. but would definitely appreciate if some one can give a logical explanation to this.

Comment: I am having the same issue. It seems, I too have to wait for a day ...